# extjs 6.0 create a treelist NavigationTree

Tags: extjs, extjs5, extjs6

has anyone here create a treelist by extjs ,I know the sources of this sample are in the extjs version, but i have no idea how to get the treelist

just because it **Highly integrated** by mvc , 
I create my workspace like this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3BfyX.png)

But when I saw the source code , I don't know which one is view, which one is model or store and how they work together.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3BfyX.png)

sorry my question is silly,hope someone can help me!! thanks a lot

Comment: sorry ,my workspace like this:
App->
 controller; 
 view -> viewport.js ; 
 model ;
store ;

Comment: A `ViewModel` and a `Model` do have as much in common as a DragQueen and a Queen.

Answer (score 0):

You can read admin-dashboard template example. Its easy to learn max of thing is covered here.

This is live example link http://examples.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.0/examples/admin-dashboard/#dashboard.

For Code you can see in downloaded framework. ext-6.0.0\templates\admin-dashboard